# ascii char to char conversions Assembly x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I am trying to make an atbash cypher in assembly x86, where `'a'`s become `'z'`s, `'b'`s become `'y'`s, and so on. I'm using the equation such that (122-char) + 97 (in ascii values) is the atbash character.

```
mov     al, 'c'
mov     rax, 122
mov     rcx, al
sub     rax, rcx
add     rax, 97
```

When executing these lines however, it says there is an invalid combination of opcode and operands.

How do i perform this equation with `char`s and `int`s correctly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The valid operands for `mov` are outlined on https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov. There is no `r64, r/m8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to zero- or sign-extend a byte into a 64-bit register, use `movzx ecx, al` or `movsx rcx, al` respectively.

Note that you were getting "invalid combination of opcode and operands" when *assembling*, before there's any machine code to execute.  That's because you picked a mnemonic (`mov`) that has no valid encoding for those operands.

---

`(122-char) + 97` = **`122+97 - char` which is trivial to implement**.  122+97 = 219 which is still only 1 byte, so you could use 8-bit operand-size if you wanted to.

```
;; input in EAX or AL
;; result in ECX or CL
mov   ecx, 'z'+'a'         ; let the assembler do the math with ASCII constants
sub   ecx, eax
```

Or in one register with worse latency:

```
sub   al, 'z'+'a'       ; c - 219
neg   al                ; 219 - c
```

Comment: Thanks! The following worked for me:                                                  
        


    movzx   rax, al

        




    mov     rdx, 122




    sub     rdx, rax




    mov     rax, rdx


    movzx   rax, al

 


    add     rax, 97

Comment: @jikrinjuice: all that repeated zero-extending is totally pointless.  If you're eventually just storing the low byte, you can just use 32-bit operand-size (usually the most efficient), or 8-bit.  Also, doing both an add and subtract is also slower than `sub al, 219` / `neg al`, like I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This line: `mov rcx, al` is not valid, since there is no encoding of `mov` that has an `r64` destination and an `r/m8` source.

This line is redundant anyway:

```
mov     al, 'c'
mov     rax, 122
```

The `al` partial register is an alias for the least significant byte of the register `rax`. You are overwriting the `'c'` with `122` immediately after the next line.   If you intend to copy just the `'c'` to `rcx`, you could use the [`movzx`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movzx) instruction, which zero-extends into the full destination from the `r/m` source:

```
mov al, 'c'
movzx ecx, al ; upper 32 bits are zeroed too
```

Fortunately, unlike its 32-bit predecessor, x86_64 has a few more GPRs that you can use (`r8` to `r15`). Use some of those for the arithmetic with `122` and `97` to implement your cipher.

Comment: There is `movzx ecx, al` or `movsx rcx, al` to zero-extend or sign-extend into RCX.  Your answer implies there's simply no way to do something like that (although it's not technically wrong because the mnemonic isn't `mov`).  I don't see why you're suggesting that xor/mov/mov sequence instead of `mov ecx, 'c'`.  Or why you're using 64-bit operand-size when we know a value is zero above the low byte.

Comment: @PeterCordes Because I forgot that movzx existed for a minute there

Comment: `movzx` doesn't exist with an immediate source, only `movzx r32, r/m8` and `movzx r32, r/m16`.  Unfortunately even x86-64 didn't repurpose any opcodes for `mov r/m32, imm8` for more compact encoding of putting small constants in registers or memory.  Any one of the opcodes like `pop ds` could have been repurposed for that, but AMD was conservative.

Comment: Huh?  The reason a separate opcode for  `add r/m32, imm8` exists as well as `add r/m32, imm32` is to increase code density / save space in memory and L1i cache.  `mov`-immediate with small integers (that need to be padded to 32-bit) is less common `add`, but compilers definitely use it for zeroing memory with an immediate of zero.  (Instead of xor-zeroing a register and storing that.)  `mov eax, 'c'` / `mov ecx, eax` would be more efficient than what you're proposing, but larger.  (5 + 2 bytes vs. your 2 + 3 bytes).  But yours has a false dependency on the old RAX.